# Valid characters in field identifiers of binary package control file

Tags: package-management, python, packaging, debian

What are the restrictions on characters in [debian binary package control files](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/#s-binarycontrolfiles) within Ubuntu?

python-tempest currently uses an identifier called [Python_version in the control file in trusty](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/tempest/trusty/view/head:/debian/control#L64) and this trips up python_support.py while parsing the Package file.

I've not found documentation for whether an underscore such as the one used by the python-tempest package is valid as a field identifier or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Debian Policy Manual, [5.1 *Syntax of control files*](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/#syntax-of-control-files):

> Each paragraph consists of a series of data fields. Each field
>   consists of the field name followed by a colon and then the data/value
>   associated with that field. The field name is composed of US-ASCII
>   characters excluding control characters, space, and colon (i.e.,
>   characters in the ranges U+0021 (`!`) through U+0039 (`9`), and U+003B
>   (`;`) through U+007E (`~`), inclusive). Field names must not begin
>   with the comment character (U+0023 `#`), nor with the hyphen character
>   (U+002D `-`).

Seems like `_` is a perfectly valid character for a `control` field name.

Comment: though that means the regex is still missing a whole bunch of other valid characters.

Comment: @GerhardPoul probably worth filing a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone finds a specification, it would be great to add this as the answer; for the time being I'll go with the source which is at [debian_support.py of the python-debian package](https://anonscm.debian.org/git/pkg-python-debian/python-debian.git/tree/lib/debian/debian_support.py).

Currently it uses this regular expression to parse the package control file:

```
^([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9-_]+):(?:\s*(.*?))?\s*$
```